# how to check the check box in ListView and change the text in same row in listView?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, textview

I have list view with check box and text view. When i checked check box, change the text in same row. This way i will check all the check boxes in list view and change the text in every row. Can any one explain with sample code?

```
public class DialogAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    //private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ArrayList<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    Context context;

    public DialogAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> timeList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub         

        this.context = context;
        this.timeList = timeList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return timings.size();
        return timeList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return timeList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //String timing = "10-30,14-08,16-30,19-00";
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_row_list,null);

        //timeListView.setVisibility(convertView.VISIBLE);

        TextView txt_time=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_times);
        txt_time.setText(timeList.get(position).toString());

        EditText comments=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText_comment);


        final TextView txt_Action=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_act);

        CheckBox cBox= (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_action);

        cBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag(); 
                 timeList.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                 Toast.makeText(context, "position"+getPosition, 0).show();
                 if(isChecked){
                        txt_Action.setText("finished");
                        txt_Action.setTextColor(R.color.Green);
                    }
                    else{
                        txt_Action.setText("UnChecked");
                        txt_Action.setTextColor(R.color.Red);
                    }
            }


        });


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

this is my code please check n give solution how to change listview text when check checkbox in listview???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `getView` method of your `ListView` adapter:

```
if(yourCheckBox.isChecked)
           yourTextView.setText("text if checkBox is checked.");
else
           yourTextView.setText("text if checkBox is not checked.");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is view before `checkboxes` and `texviews` that is `listview` ,if u want to access `textviews` from `listview` please make sure you are accessing from `listview` one item layout
Like

```
TextView txtvw=findViewByID(ur_layout_of_list_item).findViewByID(ur_textview);
```

after that changes will be done.

Answer (score 0):

First I will suggest you to use ViewHolder pattern for listview adapter so that you don't need to do `findViewById()` everytime you scroll your list this will prevent your listview from performance slow down and also I would prefer to use `setOnClickListener()` over `CheckedChangeListener()`.

Below is the sample code you can try

```
public class CustomAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    public static ArrayList<Item> modelArrayList;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> modelArrayList){

        this.context = context;
        this.modelArrayList = modelArrayList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return modelArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_list_view_row_items, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Item currentItem = (Item) getItem(position);
    if(currentItem.isChecked())
        viewHolder.tvName.setText("Checked);
    else
        viewHolder.tvName.setText("Unchecked);

    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(currentItem.isChecked());
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final boolean checked = currentItem.isChecked();
        if(checked){
           viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(!checked);
           viewHolder.tvName.setText("Unchecked");
           currentItem.setChecked(!checked);  
        }else{
           viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checked);
           viewHolder.tvName.setText("Checked");
           currentItem.setChecked(checked);  

        }

    }

  });
    return convertView;
    }

private class ViewHolder {

    protected CheckBox checkBox;
    private TextView tvName;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

}
}
```